# How do i call an image from a folder using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to call an image from a folder using css.

I have tested the css with background color, so i know it is linked and working properly.

**what I've tried:**
I have tried to call an image from outside the image folder.
I have tried to change the image type to png.
And i have tried a different image.

**html**

```
<section id="hero">
   <div class="hero container">
    <h1>testing</h1>
   </div>
 </section>
```

**css**

```
#hero{
 background-image: url(img/Computer_repair(1).jpg); 
}
```

Comment: your code works, you just have to make sure you put the right path for your image in the url

Comment: I would try to omit the brackets ( ) in the file name. Apart from that it can only be an issue with the filepath.

Comment: Or wrap the file path in quote marks, to avoid the brackets from being interpretted as syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was it was not working with the (1).
I Needed to change from Computer_repair(1).jpg to Computer_repair_1.jpg

**HTML**

```
    <section id="hero">
      <div class="hero container">
      <h1>testing</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
```

**Css**

```
#hero{
 background-image: url(img/Computer_repair_1.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works ([see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zjLcd1qs/)) so I'm assuming you just have the image path wrong.

So when you say...

```
#hero{
 background-image: url(img/Computer_repair(1).jpg);
}
```

...that means where ever your css file is saved, there also needs to be a folder called *img* and inside that folder is where you need to put *Computer_repair(1).jpg*

Comment: yes there is a folder called img that had the img inside

Comment: it was the (1). Don't know why because I have used it like that before, but that is what fixed it.  Thank you for showing me that it worked though!

Comment: Ah that makes sense because the ) in (1) can act as a closing to the opening parentheses. So when you use url(....(1)<---this ends the URL container.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. I suspect there's a problem with the image path. Try this:

```
background-image: url('/img/Computer_repair(1).jpg');
```